# Symfony - New object created instead of update

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.1

I have `Apparel` and `User` classes. Each `user` can have many `apparels`. And `apparel` can be belong to only one `User`

```
class Apparel
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="apparels", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $user;    
}


class User 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Apparel", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $apparels;
}
```

The problem is that new user are added to database when I'm updating.

- What is wrong with my code?

Here's my **Controller**

```
$user = $this->get('session')->get('user');
$apparel->setUser($user);
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entityManager->persist($apparel);
$entityManager->flush();
```

[image]

Comment: Is this the entire controller or just a portion of it?  We need to see how you are instantiating `$apparel` or doing the DB lookup.

Comment: It is just partion of controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the reason a new user is being created is because you are working with an object that is not being managed by Doctrine and probably allowing cascade creation.

So my recommendation would be to get the User Id from the session and try,

```
$user = $userRepository->find($userId)
```

and then call,

```
$apparel->setUser($user);
```

Comment: It doesn't work because I write my user to session after login. $session = $this->get('session');
    $session->set('user', $user);

Comment: Then you'll need to retrieve your user object from the database before you call `$apparel->setUser($user)`.  My guess is that the reason a new user is being created is because you are working with an object that is not being managed by Doctrine and probably allowing cascade creation.  

So my recommendation would be to get the User Id from the session and try `$user = $userRepository->find($userId)`